# Latex itemize: text gets cut off

Tags: r-markdown, pdflatex

I want to make a list in my markdown document.
I'm using Latex.

I wrote this:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item Seniors are more often killed in daytime during the working week (72% versus 58% among all age groups).
  \item There are proportionately more fatalities on urban roads (53% versus 38%) and consequently fewer on rural roads and motorways.
  \item They are relatively more often killed at intersections (15% versus 10%) and less often (but still frequently) on road stretches (74% versus 81%).
  \item Fatalities among senior car drivers were less often involved in a single crash, i.e. a crash in which only one vehicle and no pedestrians are involved (35% versus 44%).
\end{itemize}
```

But the text gets cut off at the end of the page.
[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Freya

Comment: % means comment in latex so after the percentage the rest of the line is commented out. To fix this you can use `\%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```latex
\begin{itemize}
  \item Seniors are more often killed in daytime during the working week (72\% versus 58\% among all age groups).
  \item There are proportionately more fatalities on urban roads (53\% versus 38\%) and consequently fewer on rural roads and motorways.
  \item They are relatively more often killed at intersections (15\% versus 10\%) and less often (but still frequently) on road stretches (74\% versus 81\%).
  \item Fatalities among senior car drivers were less often involved in a single crash, i.e. a crash in which only one vehicle and no pedestrians are involved (35\% versus 44\%).
\end{itemize}
```

The text is not being cut off but rather commented out by the percentage sign. See: https://texblog.org/2007/12/31/commenting-in-latex/.

For future, I recommend that you use a text editor that would likely point this out to you visually (highlighting it in green). I personally use vscode with the LaTeX language extension, but I think TexShop is also commonly used.

Also, for any other TeX related questions that you have, I recommend going over to https://tex.stackexchange.com/ which is part of the same family of sites as StackOverflow as its a dedicated place for TeX questions!

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed! I'm pretty new to using Latex for my PDF documents, I will definitely use a text editor in the future!

Comment: Glad to hear it, best of luck!